# poll returns zero even though there is data to be read in from the file descritors i specified

Tags: c++, http, network-programming, webserver, nonblocking

I've been working on making a simple HTTP server and I got stuck with this problem for almost a week

with I run siege to test the server it runs perfectly for some time and then it blocks and when I debug it I found out that the poll() return 0 as if there is no fd ready to read here's my code :

```
    while (1)
    {
        int ret = poll(&this->test[0],this->test.size(),1000);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            std::perror("webserv(poll)");
            return ;
        }
        //else if (ret == 0)
        //{
            std::cout <<  "size : " << this->test.size() <<  " and flags are : " << this->test[0].revents << std::endl;
            //continue;
        //}
        for (size_t i = 0; i < this->test.size(); i++)
        {
            if (this->test[i].revents  & POLLHUP)
            {
                std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
                close(this->test[i].fd);
                this->test.erase(this->test.begin() + i);
            }
            else if (this->test[i].revents & POLLIN)
            {
                if (this->test[i].fd == 3)
                {
                    std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
                    socklen_t addr_size = sizeof client_struct;
                    int client_fd = accept(this->test[i].fd, &client_struct,&addr_size);
                    if (client_fd < 0)
                    {
                        perror("webserv(accept)");
                        return ;
                    }
                    assign_poll.fd = client_fd;
                    assign_poll.events = POLLIN;
                    this->test.push_back(assign_poll);
                }
                else 
                {
                    std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
                    char buf[1000011];
                    ssize_t s = recv(this->test[i].fd,buf,1000000,0);
                    buf[s] = 0;
                    this->test[i].events = POLLOUT;
                    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else if (this->test[i].revents & POLLOUT)
            {
                std::cout << "5" << std::endl;
                if (send(this->test[i].fd,msg.c_str(),msg.length(),0) == -1)
                {
                    perror("webserv(send)");
                    return ;
                }
                close(this->test[i].fd);
                this->test.erase(this->test.begin() + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested the server with this siege flags :

```
siege --file=url --verbose --reps --concurrent=200 --no-parser
```

Comment: The documentation says: ***A return value of zero indicates that the system call timed out before any file descriptors became ready.***

Comment: @drescherjm i get this but some  file descriptors are ready to read but poll give me 0

Comment: You are adding and removing elements from `test` while you are iterating through it. That is going to screw up your iteration. DON'T increment `i` when removing an element! You are also `return`'ing if `accept()` or `send()` fails, don't do that because then you stop servicing your remaining clients. You are also not handling `recv()` failures, which includes graceful disconnects. And, putting a 1MB buffer on the call stack is not a good idea, either. Threads don't usually have that much stack space available by default. Use a smaller buffer, or else allocate it dynamically.